# Non-normality in the error term

Tags: multiple-regression, data-visualization

[image]

The above graph is taken from a sample of 3796 observations. You're asked to run a regression of ed on dist which gives " ed = 13.96 - 0.07*dist "

Then he asks, which assumption of the CLNRM assumptions does the model clearly violate? Does it affect the validity of your results?

The answer is non-normality of the error term. However, he hasn't given me an intuitive explanation as to why that is the case? How can you notice from the graph that the error term is not normally distributed?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

To see it's not normal notice that the y-variable is discrete, taking only 7 distinct values. This would be sufficient to identify that it's not normal. From the name of the variable, presumably this is years of education.

(You should also be able to see that the conditional distribution is skew -- e.g. consider a slice around dist = (3,4) and you can see more value like 12-13 than there are values like 17-18.)

(However, normality is not the only issue here to my eyes.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, how does a discrete Y variable cause non-normality in the errors? Is this because the data is skewed to the left and since the data is not normally distributed then the errors are also not normally distributed?

Comment: If the conditional distribution of Y is discrete, it's still discrete after you subtract the conditional mean.

Comment: Right. Since Y follows a discrete distribution and the error term is a linear combination of Y, the error term must not be normal. Am I on the right page?

Comment: The error term is Y minus a constant (given its x).